Cloud Run services - Internet Enabled & Traffic
I have a list of cloud run services in a project and configured as internet enabled. I have default network.  No VPC associated with Cloud Run services.
Will the traffic between cloud run services get egress'd to Internet or will it be internal to Google Cloud platform ?
I do understand if the Cloud Run services are mapped as Internal, the traffic is internal to the project.
I was expecting traffic to be internal although marked as internet enabled.  Will it be appropriate to associate VPC to bring in traffic restrictions?

What traffic restrictions do you wish to implement? Edit your post and explain what problem you are trying to solve. Cloud Run is either public, routed to a VPC or protected by Identity Based Access Control (OIDC Identity Tokens).

Hmmm. No. There is different aspect to take into account.
First of all, the serverless services are not running in your project, I mean, the servers that run your code are not in your project, but in a Google managed project. Therefore, the serverless serverless service are NEVER in your vpc, natively. You must plug them to it to be able to route the traffic in your VPC.
That being said, you must also take care of the traffic direction: egress and ingress.
You can set the ingress internal, internal & load balancing, or all. That means only the request originated from the ingress setting are allowed to invoke your service:

internal: only the request coming from your VPC (or your VPC Service Control, or shared VPC). It also include the internal load balancer
Load Balancing: internal traffic + external load balancer traffic origin
all: all traffic origin.

Maybe it's strange to tell you that Cloud Run is not plugged to your VPC by default, but only the traffic coming from your VPC is allowed to access your Cloud Run service. In fact, your traffic is always authenticated (additional metadata in the Google Cloud network). And, when you access your Cloud Run services, and you set the ingress internal, there is an additional check on the traffic origin, like a firewall rules on the metadata of the network traffic.
Finally, you have the egress traffic. This traffic is the request initiated by the Cloud Run service itself (like an API call makes by your service). By default, the egress traffic reach directly the internet (directly from the Google managed project to the internet). You can also control the egress with a direct connection to your VPC or a serverless VPC connector. It bridge the Google managed network and your VPC. Here, you can route only the private IP (internal traffic), if you want to reach privately addressable IPs (like Compute Engine, GKE, your OnPrem environment if you have a VPN/interconnect,...). You can also set the egress to ALL, to route the private and public traffic to your VPC. Here the value is the capability to catch the internet traffic in your VPC and to wrap it in a static IP, typically with Cloud NAT.
Maybe it's not clear at the beginning, but with that in mind, re-read the documentation and perform a few tests, it will make sense ;)
